# React Native using pass parameter with Load local HTML file into WebView

Tags: react-native

How can I pass props in Webview and get the props in my local html page

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <View>
            <WebView source={require('../Web/index.html')} />
          </View>  
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass any props to html page inside your Webview.

But there is a trick by using `injectedJavascript`
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#injectedjavascript

Here is example:
https://www.undefinednull.com/2015/12/27/injecting-custom-javascript-into-react-natives-webview/

Comment: Yes i tried injectedJavascript it's working but i want to pass an dynamic object

Comment: what is the dynamic object ?

Comment: if here is the static object "window.static = 1;" you mentioned => injectedJavascript for your dynamic is `\`window.dynObj = ${JSON.stringify(your_dynObj)};\``

Comment: let say if i have a function called jsonData() which returns an array of objects, how do we inject that
ex:jsonData() {
    const items = [
      { id: 1, title: "Thomas Williams" },
      { id: 2, title: "Mary Spencer" }
      ]
    return `document.querySelector('#query').value = ${JSON.stringify(items)}` 
  }

 <WebView source={require('../Web/index.html')} 
            injectedJavaScript = {this.jsonData} />

Comment: what do you want to inject? that function definition or its returned value

Comment: returned value.

Comment: replace the `your_dynObj` inside 3rd comment with your returned value, then inside your html you can access it by `window.dynObj`

Comment: i have one more question, i need to call a function in webview through injectedJavascript, will it be possible

Comment: well, if you call a function inside your webview to use it with your outside => then it's impossible